# How to instruct the grammar to NOT generate certain methods in the ANTLR listener?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I have this grammar:

```
foo : bar EOF;
bar : 'hello';
```

The listener interface, which ANTLR generates, contains these four methods:

```
public void enterFoo(final FooParser.LicenseContext ctx);
public void exitFoo(final FooParser.LicenseContext ctx);
public void enterBar(final FooParser.LicenseContext ctx);
public void exitBar(final FooParser.LicenseContext ctx);
```

Two of them are not needed for me: `exitFoo()` and `enterBar()`. Is it possible to tell ANTLR somehow to NOT generate them in the interface? I would actually prefer to find a way to somehow tell the grammar which grammar rules need those enter/exit methods, and all others would be ignored. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot suppress the generation of any of these methods, because the parser expects them to be there when triggering the listener for each parse step.